# NuGet [Install-Package], NotImplementedException attempting package install or mvc 3 project creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, powershell, nuget, nuget-package

When attempting to install a NuGet package I get the error “The method or operation is not implemented.” This same operation works for both my colleagues. When creating a new Mvc 3 app, I get the same error in a dialog box: "The method or operation is not implemented." Does anyone know what's going on here?

```
install-package entityframework -verbose
You are downloading EntityFramework from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=242868. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Added file 'App.config.transform' to folder 'EntityFramework.4.3.1\Content'.
Added file 'Web.config.transform' to folder 'EntityFramework.4.3.1\Content'.
Added file 'EntityFramework.dll' to folder 'EntityFramework.4.3.1\lib\net40'.
Added file 'EntityFramework.xml' to folder 'EntityFramework.4.3.1\lib\net40'.
Added file 'EF4.3on.NET4.5Readme.txt' to folder 'EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Added file 'EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' to folder 'EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Added file 'EntityFramework.psd1' to folder 'EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Added file 'EntityFramework.psm1' to folder 'EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Added file 'init.ps1' to folder 'EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Added file 'install.ps1' to folder 'EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Added file 'migrate.exe' to folder 'EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Added file 'EntityFramework.4.3.1.nupkg' to folder 'EntityFramework.4.3.1'.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 4.3.1'.
Executing script file 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools\init.ps1'.
'packages.config' already exists. Skipping...
Removed file 'EntityFramework.dll' to folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\lib\net40'.
Removed file 'EntityFramework.xml' to folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\lib\net40'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\lib\net40'.
Removed file 'App.config.transform' to folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\Content'.
Removed file 'Web.config.transform' to folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\Content'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\Content'.
Removed file 'EF4.3on.NET4.5Readme.txt' to folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Removed file 'EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' to folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Removed file 'EntityFramework.psd1' to folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Removed file 'EntityFramework.psm1' to folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Removed file 'init.ps1' to folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Removed file 'install.ps1' to folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Removed file 'migrate.exe' to folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\lib'.
Removed file 'EntityFramework.4.3.1.nupkg' to folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\JRT3ZHJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 4.3.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : The method or operation is not implemented.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<< entityframework -verbose
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], NotImplementedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What version of NuGet are you using, I recently updated my copy of NuGet in order to use EntityFramework. I had to completely uninstall NuGet and then reinstall in order to use the latest EntityFramework package hope this helps!

Comment: version 1.6.21215.9133. I tried reinstalling NuGet, and when that didn't work visual studio and sp1.

Comment: this happens on other packages, beside Entity Framework. MvcSiteMap provider, Mvc3 project creation.

Comment: So its still happening after reinstalling VS completely?

Comment: Yes. Both my colleagues (which have it working) used the same installation disk I did.